# Failed to mount component using vue-js-toggle-button

Tags: vue.js

I tried to use the [plugin](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-toggle-button) for a project with Vue 2 but got a Vue warn like below.

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined

Inside vue component:

```
import ToggleButton from 'vue-js-toggle-button'
export default {
  components: { ToggleButton }
}
```

Then,

```
<toggle-button :value="true" :labels="{checked: 'Foo', unchecked: 'Bar'}"/>
```

The plugin is not that popular and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't export the toggle button into another component. You import it in whatever component you want to use it and tell Vue to use it with `Vue.use(ToggleButton)`. Then you can use it inside your component's template and export that whole component afterwards!

Example would be:

```
<template>
  <toggle-button #someOfYourValues#></toggle-button>
</template>
```

In here, you don't import anything of the ToggleButton! You just use it as a tag inside your components!

Let's move on to your main js file where all the Vue instance creation takes place. Usually, it looks similar to this:

```
<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import ToggleButton from 'vue-js-toggle-button'
  Vue.use(ToggleButton)

  new Vue({
    el: #yourDivInTheBaseHTMLFile
    # some other stuff for your vue instance
  })
</script>
```

I tested it inside my own current Vue project, which is a todo list with lots of components. It literally works inside every single one of them when you do a `Vue.use()`.
If needed, I can link you to the project so you can have a look, but this simple explanation should do it ;)

Comment: aha! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

For completeness (Vue SFC Class):

src/main.ts:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import ToggleButton from 'vue-js-toggle-button';

Vue.use(ToggleButton);

new Vue({
  ...
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

src/components/MyComponent.vue:

```js
<template>
  <toggle-button />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ... } from "vue-property-decorator";
// do NOT import the component in here

@Component({
  components: {
    // do NOT declare the component in here
  }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```